# Passing multiple variables to a Gearman worker function

Tags: php, gearman

How do you pass two variables to the same worker function? For example, say I wished to concat two strings that I pass from the client. I saw in some example code an array being used, but I can't get it to work.

```
<?php
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();

$arguments = array(
      "string1" => "hey",
      "string2" => "there"
);
$client->addTask("string_concat", $arguments);
$client->runTasks();
?>
```

This tells me it's an invalid workload however (I assume cause it's an array being passed). How should I be passing them - should I create a task for each?

Then if I can't send an array, how can I use multiple variables in the worker function. I've tried like function String_Concat($job, $job2) but then I'm not sure how I'd add them to the workload()

Here is some example code if I were able to pass arrays:

```
<?php

$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("string_concat", "String_Concat");
while ($worker->work());

function String_Concat($job)
{
    $arguments = $job->workload();
    return $arguments["string1"] . $arguments["string2"];
}
?>
```

What's the best way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should serialize it.

Something like:

```
$data = serialize( $array );
$client->addTask("string_concat", $data);
```

Then, from your worker, you could do something like...

```
if (is_string($data) && $data = unserialize($workload)) {

} else {
 // Maybe throw Exception or something?
}
```

Comment: ah - I was not aware of this serialize! Thanks a lot Layke, I managed to get it to work with:

    $data = $job->workload();    if (is_string($data) && $data = unserialize($data)) {    $var1 = $data["string1"] . $data["string2"];
                 print $var1; 
Cheers! Edit: can't get the code formatting to work - sorry for the eye sore

Comment: The PHP docs for Gearman *do* mention serializing when sending data both to and getting data from a worker where the data is not a string BUT they dont give any examples :-)